# MongoDB ref atomic insert/delete

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have a case in which I have a document A that references a document B.
This means that in order to reference / delete a newly created document B, I have two options:

1. Embed document B in document A
2. Let the application code create document B first, then update document A

**I know that MongoDB/Morphia doesn't support atomic operation** on references so you have to manage it yourself.
For my use case, it is not an option to embed document B, they are a part of an independent collection that should stay as such.

So I'm left with option 2. But I would like to know what is the best solution to manage the transactional nature of the request.
I.e. If document B is inserted/deleted but creation/deletion of the reference to document A fails, it should not be committed.

Do you rollback by reversing the operation in a try/catch/finally block?
Is there a common solution to this problem?

I use Morphia to implement the Dao.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to do something like:

```
datastore.save(b);
try {
    datastore.save(a);
} catch (Exception e) {
   datastore.delete(b);
}
```

You could do both saves in the try, of course.  This doesn't protect you against catastrophic application crashes between saves but is good enough otherwise.  There are also race conditions in the database to consider (e.g., concurrent inserts of documents with the same values for fields with unique indexes).